# jQuery sound or tone

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, can you show me the syntax for playing a sound?
I would like to return a blip or beep or something upon error.

I found something about a sound plugin at
http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?rev=5750

And when I did a search for "sound" in the jQuery documentation, it said 
[There is no page titled "sound"](http://docs.jquery.com/Special:Search?ns0=1&search=sound&go=).

I'd be happy with a tone just as well, if there is a sound generator built into most browsers instead of requiring a Flash plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link that you provide](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?rev=5750) shows how you would use the plugin as well as how it is implemented.

In this case, it injects an `embed` element dynamically into the page, relying on the browser's native support for the file type that is returned from the `url` parameter.

In this case, you would have to have the `url` parameter point to a url on your server which represents the sound/tone you wish to play.